# Scorpion in Ohrid, Macedonia, 5cm long

Tags: species-identification

[image]

Hi, can u please help to identify what kind of scorpion is this? A friend of mine found it at home, in urban area in Ohrid, Macedonia. It is aroun 5 cm long.
Thank you.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euscorpius_italicus